# how to prove $1/2n < \sqrt{1+n²}-n$

Tags: inequality

how to prove $$1/(2n) < \sqrt{1+n²}-n$$ where n is one of those secret positive non zero real numbers

i tried doing 1/(2n) minus $\sqrt{1+n²}-n$ but i couldn't find something reliable! if one helps me i will be very thankful to him or her

Comment: The inequality doesn't hold for $n=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt{1+n^2}-n=\frac1{\color{red}{\sqrt{1+n^2}}+n}\lt\frac1{\color{red}{n}+n}=\frac1{2n}$$

Comment: Note that the inequality is reversed.